# Cakephp 3 - CRUD plugin - Use id from auth component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, crud

Currently, I'm using the CRUD v4 plugin for Cakephp 3. For the edit function in my user controller it is important that only a user itself can alter his or her credentials. I want to make this possible by inserting the user id from the authentication component. The following controller method:

```
public function edit($id = null){
    $this->Crud->on('beforeSave', function(\Cake\Event\Event $event) {
        $event->subject()->entity->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
    });
    return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```

How can I make sure I don't need to give the id through the url? The standard implementation requires the url give like this: http://domain.com/api/users/edit/1.json through PUT request. What I want to do is that a user can just fill in http://domain.com/api/users/edit.json and send a JSON body with it.

I already tried several things under which:

- $id = null when the parameter is given, like in the example above. Without giving any id in the url this will throw a 404 error which is caused by the _notFound method in the FindMethodTrait.php
- Use beforeFind instead of beforeSave. This doesn't work either since this isn't the appropriate method for the edit function.
- Give just a random id which doesn't exist in the database. This will through a 404 error. I think this is the most significant sign (combined with point 1) that there is something wrong. Since I try to overwrite this value, the CRUD plugin doesn't allow me to do that in a way that my inserting value is just totally ignored (overwriting the $event->subject()->entity->id).
- Try to access the method with PUT through http://domain.com/api/users.json. This will try to route the action to the index method.
- Just a few checks: the controllerTrait is used in my AppController and the crud edit function is not disabled.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Is this a bug?

Comment: What kind of authorization have you set up?

Comment: If you are using controller authorize in the auth component, then you should check if the user matches the url id? Is there a reason you want to remove the id from the url?

Comment: @chrisShick I'm using stateless authentication with JWT payload. The reason I want to remove the id from the url is that, the user id should be retrieved from the authentication component. In this way, I want to enforce that a user can only alter his or her credentials instead of everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would use the controller authorize in the Auth component to prevent anyone from updating someone else's information. That way you do not have to change up the crud code. Something like this...

Add this line to config of the Auth component (which is probably in your AppController):

```
'authorize' => ['Controller']
```

Then, inside the app controller create a function called isAuthorized:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    return true;
}
```

Then, inside your UsersController you can override the isAuthorized function:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
   // The owner of an article can edit and delete it
   if (in_array($this->request->action, ['edit'])) {
      $userId = (int)$this->request->params['pass'][0];
      if ($user['id'] !== $userId) {
         return false;
      }
    }
   return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

Comment: This is actually pretty clever. Currently, I enforce every rule inside the action itself which requires me to extent almost every crud action. Thanks for this insight ;).

Comment: Remember always think DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself). CakePHP is built around one such principle and will generally always have a way to help you not repeat yourself ;)